# QtQuick Gauge Needle rotation animation is not smooth

Tags: javascript, qt, animation, qml, qt-quick

I was trying to create a simple gauge using the QtQuick. The problem I am facing is that the needle rotation is not smooth. When the needle angle is changed for a higher value the needle not moving smoothly, there are some jerk in the motion and also feel like multiple needle moving. I tried to use most of the Animations Types and Easing types available but the result was negative.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
visible: true
width: 800
height: 800
color: "#00000000"

// My Needle
Rectangle{
    id: id_needle
    x: 350
    y: 350
    width: 300
    height: 5
    color: "red"
    antialiasing: true
    smooth: true
    transform: Rotation {
        id: rotation
        origin.x: 3
        origin.y: 3
        angle: 0

        Behavior on angle {

            NumberAnimation{
                duration: 1500
                easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
            }
        }
    }
}

// Sample Timer to update needle angle
Timer{
    id: tim
    repeat: true
    running: true
    interval: 2000
    onTriggered: {

        var data = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) + 0
        rotation.angle = data

     }
  }
}
```

[Video and Log](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bzwxq3lDptz7akZOVHhWVHE5akU?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide the output of running the application with the `QSG_INFO` environment variable set to `1`? A video or GIF of what you see might help as well.

Comment: Tried your code. Seems to move smoothly for me.

Comment: @Mitch: The video and the QSG_INFO logs have uploaded here [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bzwxq3lDptz7akZOVHhWVHE5akU?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your virtual machine does not have vsync,the tearing is caused by your display.